# Can't add new calendar event through Intent.ACTION_EDIT on Samsung Galaxy 3

Tags: android, calendar, widget, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm trying to develop simple widget (ICS and higher), which would use some simple shortcuts to phone calendar. I know, I know, google calendar api is unofficial, and I should use official web interface instead, etc. but I don't want - I want to use unofficial but documented calendar interface. So - I've button which should launch new event dialog:

```
Intent i7 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
i7.setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);
PendingIntent pi7 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 7, i7, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnAdd, pi7);
```

This works great on all my mobiles/tablets, but doesn't work on Samsung Galaxy 3 - it causes error:

"S Planner has failed. S planner has stopped".

It's because Samsung Galaxy phones has another calendar app - S Planner, however I would like to ask, if somebody had same problem and how do you deal with this...Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed, I added only this line:

```
i7.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
```